# React : How to add custom properties to html elements

Tags: reactjs

My use case is something like this:

I have an input element and I want a custom property for this element to be associated so that I can add string data to that specific element and retrieve it.

How should I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can us something like this:

```
<input data-customValue="somevalue" .../>
```

And then retrieve with something like:

```
let customValue = element.dataset.customValue;
```